# $\sigma \in \mathrm{Gal}(K/k), \sigma \alpha \ne \alpha$, but why is $\alpha \in k$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

> Suppose that $k$ contains $\zeta$, a primitive $p$-th root of unity where $p$ is prime, and that $K$ is Galois over $k$ with $[K : k]=p$; and write $G=\operatorname{Gal}(K / k) \approx C_p$.
>   Show that $K=k\left(\sqrt[p]{\alpha}\right)$ for some $\alpha \in k$.
>
> **Hint:** Let $\sigma$ be a generator of $G$. Take $$\alpha=\sum_0^{p-1} \zeta^{\nu} \cdot \sigma^{\nu} \beta$$ for $\beta \in K$ and show that one can choose $\beta$ so that $\alpha \neq 0$.

But with a simple try, I find that
$$
\sigma \alpha=\sum_{0}^{p-1} \zeta^{\nu} \cdot \sigma^{\nu+1} \beta\neq\alpha,
$$
so why is $\alpha$ in k?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: [Here's what I see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJL6g.jpg)

Comment: @Shaun I tried to edit

Answer (score 2):

This is just conflicting notation. The $\alpha$ in the hint is not the $\alpha$ in the assertion.

Show that you can find $\beta\in K$ such that $\gamma:= \sum_{\nu=0}^{p-1}\zeta^\nu\cdot \sigma^\nu(\beta)\neq 0$. Observe that $\sigma(\gamma) = \zeta^{-1}\gamma$ and conclude $\gamma\in K\setminus k$ and $\alpha:=\gamma^p \in k$.